How to send confirmation email when creating a user directly in Strapi entityService
So I have the default user( from strapi's user-permissions plugin) table and a user-profile table. I am trying to combine the registration process in a single endpoint. When I use the default endpoint to register a user, the email is sent correctly but when I create the user directly it doesn't send anything. The controller for that endpoint looks like this:
 async register(ctx) {
        try {
            let { firstName, lastName, nickname, email, phoneNumber, password, confirmPassword } = ctx.request.body

            if (password != confirmPassword) {
                return "password and confirmation do not match"
            }

            // I create the new user in this line
            let entry = await strapi.entityService.create("plugin::users-permissions.user", {
                data: {
                    username: nickname,
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }
            });

            if (entry == null) {
                return "There was an error with the user creation"
            }

            let entryUser = await strapi.entityService.create("api::user-profile.user-profile", {
                data: {
                    nickname: nickname,
                    first_name: firstName,
                    last_name: lastName,
                    phone_number: phoneNumber,
                }
            })

            if (entryUser == null) {
                return "There was an error with the user creation"
            }
            ctx.body = entryUser
        } catch (err) {
            ctx.body = err;
        }
    }

How can I make it so this sends the confirmation email?

The default Register controller function in Strapi is here:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/develop/packages/plugins/users-permissions/server/controllers/auth.js#L275
Here is the line that send the email for account confirmation:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/develop/packages/plugins/users-permissions/server/controllers/auth.js#L383
You will have to add that line to your custom code in order to send the confirmation email.
By default when you "create" a user thanks to the "entityService", this will just create the User in the database, without the trigger of any additional logic.
